# What does the with() method of jMock do?

Tags: java, tdd, jmock

I see with() method being used with assertThat() method in test driven development, but I don't understand what with() does. Could somebody explain with a clear example. I can't seem to find anything on it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It allows you to specify a set of acceptable inputs.  I think it's intended to read like English, for example  "calling add with any integer."

Here's a sample from the cheat sheet linked below:

```
allowing (calculator).add(with(any(int.class)), with(any(int.class)));
```

http://jmock.org/cheat-sheet.html